# Como complementar estas consultas para pegar os dados do comprador no banco?

Tags: sql, array, wordpress, foreach

Eu fiz estas consultas abaixo para pegar os dados do banco de dados do comprador e dos produtos que ele comprou. Com a primeira consulta, eu peguei o **ID** dos pedidos e com estes **IDS** eu fiz um novo `foreach` que pegou os produtos que cada **ID** adquiriu.

O que eu precisava agora era comparar o **ID** do pedido com outra tabela que contenha os dados do cliente que tem aquele determinado **ID**. Essa tabela é com 99% de chance essa aqui >>> **wp_postmeta**. Estamos falando do WordPress mas a consulta pode ser SQL nativa mesmo.

Vou mostrar o que eu fiz e o que eu consegui:

```
global $wpdb;

$sqlSelect  = "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'";

/* Buscando os IDS da Compra */
$pid = array();    
foreach ($wpdb->get_results($sqlSelect) as $dados) {
    $pid[] .= $dados->ID;
}

/* Buscando os produtos comprados pelo ID */
foreach ($pid as $uid) {
    echo '<strong>Número do pedido: ' . $uid . "</strong><br>";
    $sqlDados = "SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = '$uid'";
    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($sqlDados) as $itens) {
        echo $itens->order_item_name . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

> **Esta consulta me retornou isto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora só falta mesmo eu retornar os dados do cliente para conseguir fazer o meu programa. Podem me ajudar?

Preview da tabela `wp_postmeta` ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: wp_posts  é uma view? você não tem como fazer uma view só para isso?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não tem nada haver com view, estou armazenando dados pra posterior fazer um "sisteminha" em cima destes dados. Wp_posts é só uma tabela que registrou o pedido.

Comment: o titulo da pergunta diz.   `Como complementar estas consultas para pegar os dados do comprador no banco? ` agora se você esta armazenando deveria mudar a pergunta.

Comment: Pelo que falou daria pra fazer tudo o que quer com apenas uma query, Alguma dificuldade com JOIN ?

Comment: @FábioPaiva não tenho experiência com **JOIN** ainda mas com certeza dá pra fazer com uma só consulta.

Comment: Isso seria +- assim `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts as p
join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi
on oi.order_id = p.id
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'` , mas como falei veja a possibilidade de ser uma `View`, caso o baco aceite.

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo de JOIN

```
$sqlSelect  = 'SELECT pt.ID, woi.*, cli.* '
          . 'FROM wp_posts pt '
          . 'INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items woi ON (woi.order_id = pt.id) '
          . 'INNER JOIN wp_nome_tabela_clientes cli ON (cli.id = pt.cliente_id) '
          . 'WHERE pt.post_type = "shop_order" ';
```

Comment: Cara eu estava vendo aqui o código da sua resposta e acho que não me ajuda porque você ignorou a parte principal da pergunta, a tabela **wp_postmeta** que contém todos os dados do cliente por ID do pedido.